# Is it possible to use Visual Studio HTML formatting to format an embedded code block?

Tags: visual-studio, code-formatting

I love Visual Studio's ability to auto format (CTRL + K,D).  However, in HTML if you have something like:

```
<h1><%# Eval("SomeField") %></h1>
```

It gets formatted this way:

```
<h1>
    <%# Eval("SomeField") %></h1>
```

I'm fairly certain that the line break after the `<h1>` tag is caused by Visual Studio's formatting rules for embedded code blocks.  However I don't know where to edit those settings.  All of the other rules are under Tools > Options > Text Editor.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tools > Options > Text Editor > Html > Formatting

Tag wrapping section -> Tag Specific Options...

Default Settings (there are 4) - Change all the "Line breaks:" to "Before and after"

Comment: That was the correct setting, but the value needed to be "None" in order to make it work the way I wanted it to (<h1><%# Eval("Field") %></h1>).  Thanks for the lead!

Answer (score 2):

You were close...

Go to Tools > Options > Text Editor > Html > Format

In the tag wrapping section, click on **"Tag Specific Options"**

In the tree, under the **"Client HTML Tags"** node you'll see the ***embed*** element.

Set its line breaks to **"Before Opening,within, and after closing."**

Comment: I thought that as a possibility too, but after trying it, I realized that option is for the HTML tag <embed></embed>.  Thanks for taking a stab.

Answer (score 0):

Tag Specific Options->Default Settings->Client tag does not support content.

Set the Line Breaks to after tag.